# Linux on a tablet with an SD card?

Tags: android, linux, tablet, sd-card, android-sdcard

On a tablet, is it possible to install Linux on an SD card, and let it boot from it without the need to partition the internal memory and without touching Android?

Comment: please ask on http://android.stackexchange.com/  or http://xda-developers.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a native boot, out of the box, no. Android tablets generally have a locked bootloader and there would likely be driver issues. However, [it has been done](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2195778). For this to be done, however, you need to do quite a bit to the tablet.

I recommend you research which distribution of linux you want running on a tablet, then look for guides (such as on xda-developers.com), then buy the corresponding tablet.

Answer (score 1):

You can emulate linux on your android phone. Take a look at this app:https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zpwebsites.linuxonandroid&hl=en